# Error converting datatype nvarchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am getting the error

> Error converting datatype nvarchar to int

Code:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_rcdoc]
  @regno int,
  @appname varchar(50),
  @DOI datetime,
  @COV varchar(50),
  @validtill date,
  @imgloc varchar(500),
  @ImagNo char(20),
  @Purposecode varchar(50),
  @FLAG varchar(3)
AS BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT regno FROM tblRCDocuments WHERE regno = @regno)
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO tblRCDocuments(regno, appname, DOI, COV, validtill, imgloc, ImagNo, Purposecode, FLAG) 
       VALUES(@regno, @appname, @DOI, @COV, @validtill, @imgloc, @ImagNo, @Purposecode, @FLAG)
   END
```

Comment: Please post the structure of tblRCDocuments

Comment: you passing the parameter for regno is string datatype which reflect the error as you mention. Pass the int type value for regno.

Comment: OK, so just debug this - what values are you passing into the stored proc?? What if you call that `INSERT` statement manually, in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, with those parameters??

Answer (score 9):

Looks like regno is a nvarchar data type in your table and you have passed an int via your your procedure, either use a cast and convert @regno to an nvarchar or change the regno data type to an integer in the table.

```
DECLARE @regnocast NVARCHAR(15)

SET @regnocast = CAST(@regno AS NVARCHAR)
```

Then in your SELECT, INSERT and WHERE clauses use @regnocast rather than @regno

Comment: Thanks to every one for the help

Comment: Also: I would recommend to always specify an explicit **length** when you do a cast. By default, if you don't specify anything - it'll be 30 characters. If that's fine - great - but it's clearer if you say so: `CAST(@regno AS NVARCHAR(20))` or whatever you need...